# Angular and Routing to Component page on button click event

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-routing

I'm new to Angular routing and I've been banging my head against the wall with this issue.

So I have a button in a table that when clicked calls an action method based on what type of button it is. So my button in question is a Task button and is declared as such

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="callActionEvent($event, 'task', job)">Tasks</button>
```

In the component page that contains the 'callActionEvent' I am declaring the constructor as such

```
constructor(private jobService: JobsService, public router: Router) {
  this.router = inject(Router);
}
```

The code behind for the 'callActionEvent' is this

```
callActionEvent(event: Event, actionType: string, job: Job) {

  this.actionHandler = new ActionHandler(this.router);
  this.actionHandler.callActionEvent(job.jobid, actionType);
```

Here's the code for the ActionHandler

import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

import { JobTasksComponent } from 'src/app/portals/lob-research/screens/job-tasks/job-tasks.component';

```
export class ActionHandler {

    constructor( public _router: Router ) {
      this._router = inject(Router);
    }

    jobTasksComponent: JobTasksComponent;

    callActionEvent(jobid: number, actionType: string) {

        switch (actionType) {
            case 'task': {
              console.log(actionType, jobid);
              return this._router.navigate([this.jobTasksComponent]);
            }
        }
        return true;
      }

}
```

From what I've read everything looks right but when I run the application and *this.actionHandler = new ActionHandler(this.router);* is being called I'm getting the following error

```
Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor,...
```

Like I said from what I can see everything looks right but obviously not otherwise I wouldn't keep getting this error.

Comment: Why do you have that `inject` line at all, it seems to me that's not needed.

Comment: It's in there because that is what on of the posts on this side said needed to be done and the person who asked the question said that recommendation fixed their issue

Comment: So I removed those 2 calls to inject and I made it to the actionHandler return this._router.navigate([this.jobTasksComponent]); call and I'm getting 'The requested path contains undefined segment at index 0' so onto t/s my route component -thank you